# Implementing lightning component with number of lookup fields in community

Tags: lightning, lookup, lightning-community, lookup-filter

I'm trying to implement a component with lookup `fields`. The form is to be created dynamically. I tried the following ways :

> **Approach 1**

Using `<lightning:inputField>` with `<lightning:recordEditForm>`. The component is working fine in org but it's not populating the record search window in the community(popup appears after clicking the "`search 'xyz value' in 'object name'`" below the lookup field). I think it may be some salesforce issue as the code breaking when I click on search option. Also, there are some fields which are having `lookup filter`. And this also not working in the community as well as in org. 
So, changed the approach to next.

> Approach 2

Using [LDS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_create_record.htm). But soon after I came to know as of now [LDS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_create_record.htm) is not supported in community

Again I need to change the approach.

> Approach 3(but least interested)

Using custom lookup fields. As the number of lookup fields is not fixed(may vary up to 10). I think this approach may affect the overall performance of the component, as this complete problem is just a part of my component.
Least interested to solve this way.

For approach 1 reference please [see this](https://pasteboard.co/HUBPAMn.png) and [error](https://pasteboard.co/HUBQNPz.png) encountered

Is there any better approach to proceed?

> Edited:

Beloew is the code I used in approach 1.

```
    <lightning:recordEditForm
                             aura:id="editRForm"
                             objectApiName="{!v.objAPIName}"                                                      
                             onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                             >
          <lightning:messages />
          <aura:iteration items="{!v.FieldAPINames}" var="i">                                    
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!i}" aura:id="editFormField"/>
          </aura:iteration>
          <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" class=" slds-float_right slds-m-top_medium"/>
   </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: Hi there, Happy new year! As written, the questions is opinion-based and fairly broad. I'd recommend you pick an approach and post the relevant code, then we (the community) can help you get unstuck and get your question solved.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Kessel, please refer the edited section for the code I used.